# if or statement to create a new column from time data in R

Tags: r, time, posixlt

I have a small dataset containing some date/time information. e.g.:

```
type    start       end         price time
rental  location A  Location B  0   23:50:00
rental  location A  Location B  0   18:32:00
rental  location A  Location B  0   10:10:00
rental  location A  Location B  0   09:54:00
rental  location A  Location B  0   20:48:00
```

I want to write a set of if/or statements in R to create a new column (price) that displays a price for on and off peak times. This is a data set showing bike rental times, and I want to compare it to the cost of peak time public transit travel. 
So, there are two values possible in the column `price`: $2.9 and $2.4.

Peak times are between 6:30-9:30 and 16:30-19:30.
there has to be a better way to do this, but now I wrote the following set of conditions:

First, I used `as.POSIXlt` so I could use `$hour` and `$min` to split out the hours and minutes from the data individually.

The data frame to begin with is `data`

```
time2 <- strptime(data$time, "%H:%M:%OS")
posixlt <- as.POSIXlt(time2, format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
names(unclass(posixlt))
peak <- posixlt
```

from the new `peak` column containing times, I want to generate a new data.frame that contains the original data and a separate column for hours and minutes.

```
df <-cbind(data,peak$hour, peak$min)
as.numeric(peak$hour)
as.numeric(peak$min)
```

Now I set my conditions to account for the different time possibilities and the respective prices in the `df$price` column.

```
df$price[peak$hour <6] <- 2.4
df$price[((peak$hour >= 6) & (peak$hour <=9))] <- 2.9
df$price[peak$hour==9 & peak$min >=30] <- 2.4
df$price[peak$hour>9 & peak$hour <=16] <- 2.4
df$price[peak$hour==16 & peak$min >=30] <- 2.9
df$price[peak$hour>16 & peak$hour<19] <- 2.9
df$price[peak$hour>19] <- 2.4
df$price[peak$hour==19 & peak$min <=30] <- 2.9
df$price[peak$hour==19 & peak$min >=30] <- 2.4
```

It worked, but there has to be a more efficient way of doing this that I am overlooking?
Perhaps I didn't need to do all the prep work with the time column, and I'm curious to see what other options there are for future reference.

Comment: If you have full date and time as POSIXct, you should be able to compare times without extracting any individual portions. Your input data has no dates to generate time objects.

Comment: thank you! the original data file did contain date and time. How would you structure the arguments then to assign a value in df$price depending on what time the trip took place?

Comment: You can use something like `df$price < ifelse(df$time >= start_of_peak_time & df$time <= end_of_peak_time, peak_price, non_peak_price)`